# CSS: Image Using 'position absolute' Hides Content

Tags: css, html

I am trying to cross fade between two images using the following setup:

```
<div id="cf">
    <img class="botton" src="images/img1.png?" />
    <img class="top" src="images/img2.png?" />
</div>

<p>this text is actually hidden but it should be visible and appear right after the image.</p>
```

CSS:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
}

#cf img {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
      opacity:0;
}
```

The crossfade works well however because I seem to be using a "position absolute", the text that follows the images is actually below the image (the image is rendered on top of the text). So it seems like the text is actually positioned at the same height than div id="cf".

How can I work around this? Thank you.

Comment: Add a `margin-top` to the paragraph tag to push it down far enough that it appears below the images.

Comment: Sure but I need something automatic because i might use this setup a lot and the height of the images might change, so I can't do this every time I use the cross fade setup (because it means I would have to adjust things by hand every time). There must be a better way?!

Comment: Apply `position:absolute;` only to one of the images(the one you want to be on top) instead of both, that way the relative positioned image will set the height of the `cf` container.

Comment: I thought I needed to use in order to get the second image on top of the first one. At least this is how the method was described here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ and it made sense to me. If you remove it, the two images are indeed rendered one after the other.

Comment: @APAD1 ah yes clever, let me try that, if it works, you can add this as an answer.

Comment: @APAD1's solution should work, you will need to ensure position abs is only applied to one element at a time with `:nth-child(odd/even)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, if you set `position:absolute` on only one of the images, the relatively positioned image will set the height of the container and you should still be able to get the desired effect.

```
.top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6NyT/1/)

OP adding his solution to the answer:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
}

#cf img {
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

#cf img.top {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I add the updated code to your answer. If you could accept the edit.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by APAD1 just add

```
#cf img.top {
  position: relative;
}
```

If your images do not have the same dimensions this will probably not work very well.

Comment: yes of course, they do have the same dimension in this case, hopefully that one problem I don't have to deal with. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that because you are using `position:absolute;` for your images, they do not take up any height in your div, thus your div has no height and the paragraph appears behind the images. You can make only the top image be absolute and that will fix your problem.
Give #cf `position:relative;` in its CSS:

```
#cf{
    position:relative;
}
```

Then apply position relative to the top image only:

```
#cf .top {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/R4S57/9/)